# iOS 17 ObjectCaptureSession beginNewScanPassAfterFlip

Tags: ios, swift, realitykit

I am trying to get an implementation of Object Capture using ObjectCaptureSession in iOS 17.

I have been following the example supplied by Apple, but I cannot get the session object to be in the correct state to allow `ObjectCaptureSession::beginNewScanPassAfterFlip()` to be called.

I get the following error when I call `session.beginNewScanPassAfterFlip()`

```
Can't beginNewScanPassAfterFlip() from state == capturing  Must be .paused from .capturing
```

To start with, there is no state of ObjectCaptureSession which is `.paused` , so is this talking about `.isPaused`?

I have tried using `session.pause()` and confirm that it is paused using `.isPaused` but I get the same error as above.

I have checked the output of `session.state`, and confirm it is `.capturing`

I have put print statements in the example, and confirm that before `session.beginNewScanPassAfterFlip()` is called at line 104 of `OnboardingButtonView` the state is `.capturing`

This goes against the documentation in this page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/objectcapturesession/beginnewscanpassafterflip()

I am hoping for some clarification if there is something I am missing?

Note, I have also tried pausing the session and calling beginNewScanPassAfterFlip() but this results in the warning.